# ASP.Net Calling method from another namespace

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database, linq-to-sql

I have two projects, the first one with a ClassLibraryServer namespace and Output method as following :

```
   namespace ClassLibraryServer
   {
   public class Output
   {
      public static void Card(tblCard card, int myProperty)
      {
        if (kort.fltNr.Length != 6)
            return;

        using (myDataContext db = new myDataContext(ClassLibrary.Settings.Instance.SqlS))
        {
            tblReader[] readers = (from row in db.tblReader  
                                   where !row.fltOffline
                                   select row).ToArray();


            bool blocked = (db.tblCardBlocked.Where(b => b.fltProperty == myProperty && b.fltCard == card.id).FirstOrDefault() != null);

            foreach (tblReader reader in readers)              
            {
                Card(card, reader, blocked);
            }
        }
      }
    }
    }
```

The Card method in foreach loop calls another method (Overloading the first card method) which has three parameters and inserts data to a sql table, I won't share it here as it takes too much space.

Now I want to call above method in another project with namespace ExtControlModule:

```
          namespace ExtControlModule

          {
            public class TimeModule
            {
             using (ModuleDataContext dbsys = new ModuleDataContext(ClassLibrary.Settings.Instance.SqlS)) {
                var loungee = (from tblLounge in dbsys.tblLounges
                               select tblLounge).ToList();

                 var lasaresFas = 0;
                 foreach (var LoungeRow in loungee)
                 {
                 lasaresFas= Convert.ToInt32(dbsys.tblLasares.FirstOrDefault(f => f.id == LoungeRow.fltCardreader).fltproperty);



                 tblCard cardLoading = dbsys.tblCard.FirstOrDefault(t => t.id == res.fltCardnumber);
                 Output.Card(cardLoading, lasaresFas);
                 }
             }
          }
```

Now when I want to assign parameters to Output.Card in ExtControlModule I get the following error in cardLoading parameter in Output.Card:

Argument !: cannot convert from 'ExtControlModule.tblCard' to ClassLibrary.db.tblCard'

ClassLibrary is another project in the same Solution which contains a public class Settings with the SqlS property which facilitate connection to SQL database.

Struggling with this for many days as I am new to both ASP.NET and Sql, hope my question is clear enough.

Comment: try using fully qualified namespace

Comment: You apparently have two classes of the same name `tblCard`. Just because they have the same name, that doesn't mean they're interchangeable. You need to change things around so that both methods you've shown (and possibly others) agree on which `tblCard` class is relevant and which assembly it belongs in. Nothing to do with namespaces, really.

Answer (score 1):

call method

```
ClassLibraryServer.Output.Card(cardLoading, lasaresFas);
```

Comment: It's a static method, no need to create an instance. They've included an error message in their question which (should) make it clear what the issue is. They're either ignoring the contents of the error message or do not understand it. Neither of those are fixed by this code.

Comment: I have made the changes :)

Comment: I am using ClassLibraryServer as directive so it does not matter,  
@Damien_The_Unbeliever tblCard is name of a table and cardLoading is an objet of that table. If I hover mouse over tblCard it points to ClassLibrary.db.tblCard in which db is database module.

Comment: @S.A.Khalili - but the error message is saying that when you've called `dbsys.tblCard.FirstOrDefault(...);`, what you've gotten back is an `ExtControlModule.tblCard`, **not** a `ClassLibrary.db.tblCard`. As I commented below your question several hours ago, you have *two* `tblCard` classes and you're trying to use one where the other is required.